# Mysql change column details

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I am trying to redefine the number of varchars a column can have (in a MySQL db).

I am doing

```
alter table obj_details IMG_SRC IMG_SRC varchar(180);
```

I want to change the number of characters that can be used in the column IMG_SRC to 180 (it is currently 100). But I get an error saying that I should check the syntax near IMG_SRC IMG_SRC varchar(180).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why did you write `IMG_SRC` twice? You want:

```
ALTER TABLE obj_details MODIFY IMG_SRC varchar(180);
```

(For what it's worth the `COLUMN` in `MODIFY COLUMN` is optional, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html).)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing `MODIFY COLUMN`, and you're specifying `IMG_SRC` twice for some reason.

Try this instead,

```
ALTER TABLE `obj_details` MODIFY COLUMN `IMG_SRC` VARCHAR(180);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you mean is:

```
alter table obj_details modify IMG_SRC varchar(180);
```